# Possible to pass set operators (operation) as a string argument to a function?

Tags: python, set, arguments

My question shall be easily understood with the following pseudo example code:

```
def set_operation(a,b,c,operation):
    stringrun(operation)  # stringrun is the pseudo element here ;)

set_operation(set([1,2,3]),set([4,5,6]),set([3,4]), "(a|b)^c")
>>> set([1,2,5,6])
```

So what I would love to have is a such simple way to not have to write a bunch of code which analyses the *operation*-string char-per-char and getting to my final result with enough *for*s, *if*s and functions like *.union*, *.intersection* etc.
Instead it would be quite elegant, if I just could pass the set operation command directly to the function, in which I wanna work with it.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *really bad design*, but what you asked for:

```
def do_string(a, b, c, op_string):
    return eval(op_string)

a = set([1,2,3])
b = set([4,5,6])
c = set([3,4])
print(do_string(a, b, c, "(a|b)^c"))  # =>  {1, 2, 5, 6}

# be aware! arguments are passed POSITIONALLY, not by name!
print(do_string(b, c, a, "(a|b)^c"))  # =>  {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}  !not what you expected!
```

a somewhat safer method:

```
def do_fn(a, b, c, op_fn):
    return op_fn(a, b, c)

print(do_fn(a, b, c, (lambda a, b, c: (a | b) ^ c)))  # => {1, 2, 5, 6}
```

or you could just write:

```
def my_fn(a, b, c):
    return (a | b) ^ c

print(my_fn(a, b, c))     # => {1, 2, 5, 6}
```

(I know, that's *boring* ;-)

Comment: Built-in method, eval(), sure, should have had there a deeper look for solving my problem. At least exactly what I wanted. Thanks!
So why would you say it's "really bad design"? Well, the second solution looks useful too, but isn't handy enough. The third for sure is no real (dynamic) solution ;)